# Web service returns blank page instead of JSON object

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf

I have been asked to develop a WCF web service as a project for the first time. The web service is rather simple, it should just return a JSON object. 
The problem is that the browser (chrome,f irefox) shows a blank page while trying to test the service using the browser. The WcfTestClient shows the JSON output correctly.

attached is my Code and the Web.config

So what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService3.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService3.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**IService1.cs:**

```
namespace WcfService3
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(string username, string password);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Service1.svc.cs:**

```
namespace WcfService3
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "data/{user}/{pass}")]
        public string GetData(string user, string pass)
        {
            Data UserData = new Data()
            {
                Username = user,
                Password = pass
            };

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Data));
            ser.WriteObject(stream, UserData);
            string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            return json;
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use in a webbrowser you need to implement the webHttpBinding rather than, or along with, wsHttpBinding.

```
<services> 
  <service name="WcfService3.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService3.Service1Behavior"> 
    <!-- Service Endpoints --> 
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" contract="WcfService3.IService1"> 
      <identity> 
        <dns value="localhost"/> 
      </identity> 
    </endpoint> 
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/> 
  </service> 
</services>
```

also in Config:

```
  <endpointBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="webBehavior"> 
      <webHttp /> 
    </behavior> 
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
namespace WcfService3
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "data/{user}/{pass}")]
        public Data GetData(string user, string pass)
        {
            Data UserData = new Data()
            {
                Username = user,
                Password = pass
            };

            return UserData;
        }  
    }
}
```

You define the response format as Json so The Wcf service will translate your return object to Json. (If I am correct)